# Unity and Interfaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just testing some things out with interfaces at runtime.

I have ISuitWearer and ISuit interfaces. I have Mario that implements ISuitWearer and MarioSuit, FrogSuit that implement ISuit. The idea is to start with MarioSuit by default and when collide with an object that object will change the suit to FrogSuit for Mario.

To simulate this collide idea I just press '2' key that calls RemoveSuit() however this method doesn't work as expected. I get the current suit, which after pressing '1' key will be frog. Then remove that component and add MarioSuit component, but then `GetComponent<ISuit>()` still returns FrogSuit. If I'm explicit and change that to `GetComponent<MarioSuit>()` then it works. I'm confused as to why even though the FrogSuit no longer shows on the inspector and I removed it in the lines above and added MarioSuit why `GetComponent<ISuit>()` still returns FrogSuit? The only ISuit component on the game object is MarioSuit at that point.

**ISuitWearer.cs**

```
public interface ISuitWearer
{
    void GiveSuit<T>() where T : Component, ISuit;

    void RemoveSuit();
}
```

**ISuit.cs**

```
public interface ISuit
{
    void Jump();
}
```

**FrogSuit.cs**

```
public class FrogSuit : MonoBehaviour, ISuit
{
    public void Jump()
    {
        Debug.Log("Frog Suit Jump");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger with frog");

        other.GetComponent<ISuitWearer>()?.GiveSuit<FrogSuit>();

        // the frog suit only lasts so long so remove the suit after x seconds
        StartCoroutine(RemoveSuit(other));
    }

    private IEnumerator RemoveSuit(Collider other)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        other?.GetComponent<ISuitWearer>()?.RemoveSuit();
    }
}
```

**MarioSuit.cs**

```
public class MarioSuit : MonoBehaviour, ISuit
{
    public void Jump()
    {
        Debug.Log("Mario Suit Jump");
    }
}
```

**Mario.cs**

```
public class Mario : MonoBehaviour, ISuitWearer
{
    private ISuit suit;

    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<MarioSuit>();
        suit = GetComponent<ISuit>();
    }

    public void GiveSuit<T>() where T : Component, ISuit
    {   
        // remove current suit
        var currentSuit = GetComponent<ISuit>();
        Destroy((currentSuit as MonoBehaviour));

        // add new suit
        gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        suit = GetComponent<T>();
    }

    public void RemoveSuit()
    {
        // remove current suit
        var currentSuit = GetComponent<ISuit>();
        Destroy((currentSuit as MonoBehaviour));

        gameObject.AddComponent<MarioSuit>();
        suit = GetComponent<ISuit>();       // this still brings back FrogSuit even though above it gets removed
        //suit = GetComponent<MarioSuit>(); // this works
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { suit.Jump(); }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1)) { GiveSuit<FrogSuit>(); }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2)) { RemoveSuit(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see that the FrogSuit component doesn't actually get removed until end of frame. I added a coroutine and wait until end of frame to assign suit and then it worked.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate. That post isn't even close to what was happening.